# Get socket addresses of clients from HttpServerChannel object

Tags: .net, .net-remoting

I am currently working on a client-server application using .NET Remoting. All is working well but I would like to see specific information regarding the clients which connect to the server. 
Can anyone tell me how I can get the socket addresses of clients who are connected to my HttpServerChannel? I could only find a way with sinks but that seemed cumbersome... there has to be an easier way than scanning al messages received for the ip address. Furthermore this method only allows me to get the ip address but I would like the port number also.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!